# Traverse a tree from root to all children in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, recursion, path, tree

A simplified version of what I want to do is to turn a tree like this:
[image: sample tree]
Into an array like this: ["abc","abd","ae"]

Basically I want to traverse the tree from it's root node to each of the children.

I've tried doing this by putting a for-in loop in a recursive block, but the problem was that the for loop would start over each time the block was recursed. When I tried running the block asynchronously I kept getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can downvoter please explain down vote?

Comment: Not me on the down vote, but my guess would be that the question would have been better if it included your code, and some detail about where the code fails.

Comment: Ah, you're right. My code is unfortunately too complex, so I didn't post it :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say the tree is represented like this:

```
@interface TreeNode : NSObject
@property(weak,nonatomic) TreeNode *parent;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *children;
@end
```

The lineage (which is what you're looking for) of any node, is a list of nodes from the root to the node.  This can be defined recursively like this:

```
- (NSArray *)lineage {
    if (!self.parent) {
        return @[self];
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *lineage = [[self.parent lineage] mutableCopy];
        [lineage addObject:self];
        return lineage;
    }
}
```

You're looking for the lineages of the leaves, so we need a way to collect the leaves.  We can do that if we can traverse the tree.  This is a good application for blocks, like this:

```
- (void)depthFirst:(void (^)(TreeNode *))block {
    for (TreeNode *node in self.children) {
        [node depthFirst:block];
    }
    return block(self);
}
```

And that provides a natural way to collect leaves:

```
- (NSArray *)leaves {
    NSMutableArray *leaves = [@[] mutableCopy];
    [self depthFirst:^(TreeNode *node) {
        if (!node.children) [leaves addObject:node];
    }];
    return leaves;
}
```

Putting it together, we get:

```
- (NSArray *)lineagesOfLeaves {
    NSMutableArray lineages = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (TreeNode *leaf in [self leaves]) {
        [lineages addObject:[leaf lineage]];
    }
    return lineages;
}
```

These methods work on any node in the tree.  Though, for your question, you'll want to send `lineagesOfLeaves` to the tree's root.

Comment: You really should make the `parent` property `weak` instead of `strong`. Otherwise you have circular strong references since the array is keeping strong references to the child nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Haven't yet adapted it to my specific problem, but it worked in a simpler trial.

Comment: @danh could you explain how the depthFirst method works? I think it runs a block on the deepest leaves, is this correct? What happens to the for loop if you recurse the method it is contained in while it is running? Will it eventually finish running?

Comment: @Bogidon - depthFirst visits the receiver and every one of its descendants, including the interior nodes and leaves.  If you call it on the root, it will visit every node on the tree once.  If you call it from within the block, the recursion will work, but you'll end up visiting nodes over and over.  I would avoid calling depthFirst from inside the depthFirst block.